# GROUP BY doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sql

please advice why group by doesn't work here.
I want it to be grouped by setup_time:

```
mysql> select i_connection, avg(setup_time) from CDR_Vendors where i_env = 9 group by i_connection order by setup_time asc limit 15;
+--------------+-----------------+
| i_connection | avg(setup_time) |
+--------------+-----------------+
|            0 |          0.0000 |
|          351 |          0.0000 |
|          235 |         11.9830 |
|          376 |         77.3151 |
|          396 |        168.3036 |
|          318 |         99.0741 |
|          319 |        126.4138 |
|          317 |        366.6881 |
|          545 |       2523.9878 |
|          551 |       4811.5482 |
|          485 |       3410.2093 |
|          289 |        692.0000 |
|          239 |       4314.1667 |
|          510 |       3322.8444 |
|          546 |       2041.7491 |
+--------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Your question is fairly vague as to what you are attempting to do or what the issue is. I highly recommend reading through these as pages:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer they are both fantastic resources to use when asking or answering questions and will help you get the best answers quickly.

Comment: I'm sure that `group by` is working (it always has worked when I've used it).    After all, there is only one row per group, so the results look right to me.  You must be expecting it to do something it is not designed to do.

Comment: I think you would have more help if you rephrased your question (make it more clear), what do you mean exactly by " I want it to be grouped by setup_time" ? Because if you GROUP BY setup_time, and average it, maybe I'm making a mistake but I think it will just return the setup_time ... (average with every row having the same setup_time).

Answer (score 0):

```
select i_connection, avg(setup_time) from CDR_Vendors where i_env = 9 group by setup_time order by setup_time asc limit 15;
```

You can group by 'i_connection'.